# How to redirect from a file to another address?

Tags: .htaccess

I move my files to another server so I need to redirect user to another page, when he click on "old direct download link".

For Example when user click on:

`http://example-1.com/file.zip`

he must redirect to:

`http://example-2.com/old_file.zip`

Comment: Has the name of the file changed? Has it changed for every resource?

Comment: The title says FTP, but your URLs use HTTP.

Comment: yes, names of files changed form "file" to "old_file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `.htaccess` in the `http://example-1.com/` root:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.+\.zip)$ http://example-2.com/old_$1 [R=301,L]
```